# JS autofill incremented score, edit previous fill in

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so i wrote a JS that fills an input with the incremented score automatically when you're adding the score in the inputs. Works fine problem is how do i get around
the fact that if someone goes back to edit a previous input it first decrease the value by the previous value and then adds the corrected one to the incremented score.

How can i...check if it is an edit on the input or just an input ?

Below is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/H2SAX/2/):

```
var score = 0;
function checkField(val, inscr) {
   score = +score + +val;
   document.getElementById('incr' + inscr).value = score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can add the score for each fields for each change (not tested):

```
<input name="ex1" class="inputline1"/>
<input name="ex2" class="inputline1"/>
<input name="ex3" class="inputline1"/>
<input name="result-1" id="result-1" />
```

and in your js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inputline1").change(function(){
        $("#result-1").val(0);
        $(".inputline1").each(function(){
            $("#result-1").val($("#result-1").val() + $(this).val());
        }
    }
});
```

in this code : for all the fields of line 1 we will reset the result value and add the value of each input with class inputline1.

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

Ended up playing with the code a little bit and just made it so that it calculates again from the beggining each input and update accordingly.